# Assistance with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Have been studying on arrays and following example has been given in the book

but couldnt figure out some parts and need some assistance;

Question 1

Couldnt really figure out what this statement is doing:

```
Count[RandomArray[i]-1]++;
```

Question 2

```
Console.Write("{0,2} Adet {1,2} >>>>", Count[i], i+1)
```

whats happening when increasing i++

Many thx beforehand for your kind assistance..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] RandomArray = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            RandomArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 5); 
        }

        int[] Count = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Count[RandomArray[i]-1]++;

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,2} Adet {1,2} >>>>", Count[i], i+1);
            for (int j = 0; j < Count[i]; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Count[RandomArray[i]-1]++; just look at this from the inside-out. Take the value of RandomArray at index I, subtract 1, take the value of Count at the index you've just calculated

Comment: It's making a histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We have to count occurance of each number and then visualize it as histogram.
- We actually should use dictionary for each number and count its stats.
- But in our case we can use array, too.Cause we know that our numbers  will be within (1-5) `{1,2,3,4,5}`.So we will make 5 length array.Then we will just store `number` stats  at `(number-1)` index.
- Then when using we will know that stats at `array[index]` will 
  be our `number //number=(index+1)` stats

Now the same things with code for 100 tries:

```
    //make randomized 100 tries with {1,2,3,4,5} numbers
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] RandomArray = new int[100]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
          RandomArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 6); // 

    //Now lets count of occurance of each number
    int[] Count = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
       // Count[RandomArray[i]-1]++; 
       int number=RandomArray[i];//get our number from randomized box
       int index=number-1; // number stats will store at (number-1) index 
       //in our case we will increase our number count
       ++Count[index] ;//Count[index]+=1 
    }
```

And when visualizing those as histogram we will get stats to our number using (index+1).

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
  //number=i+1 and its stat will be at Count[i]
      Console.Write("{0,2} Adet {1,2} >>>>", Count[i], i+1);
      for (int j = 0; j < Count[i]; j++) {
            Console.Write("*");
         }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

Comment: Actually i didnt understand why this 1 is deducted... 
and then at the end, this "i++"

Comment: @user3080201 I edited my answer.Check to see if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you'll first make an array (RandomArray) filled with some random numbers between 1 and 5.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] RandomArray = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    RandomArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 5); 
}
```

++i and i++ in this case will do the same.
Actually ++i means to first add 1 before taking the value and i++ means take the value of i and add one. But as I said, this doesn't make a difference in here

Then you'll make a new array (Count) and you'll count those random numbers.
Because the random numbers are between 1 and 5, you'll need to subtract 1 from the number, otherwise you'll have OutOfBound Exceptions.

```
int[] Count = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    Count[RandomArray[i]-1]++;
}
```

After that, you'll print the results as a histogram, using a * for each counted number.
Previously, you had to use i-1 to prevent OutOfBounds Exceptions. This means that the counts of the number 1 are stored under index 0, so add 1 add the end to display the correct result

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("{0,2} Adet {1,2} >>>>", Count[i], i+1);
    for (int j = 0; j < Count[i]; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

}
```

**Example**

```
RandomArray = [1, 3, 4, 1, 5];
Count = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1];

 2 Adet  1 >>>> **
 0 Adet  2 >>>> 
 1 Adet  3 >>>> *
 1 Adet  4 >>>> *
 1 Adet  5 >>>> *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Say RandomArray comes {4,3,1,1,3}

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Count[RandomArray[i] - 1]++;
            //When i=0
           // RandomArray[i]=4
            //Count[RandomArray[i] - 1] will be Count[4-1] which will be Count[3]
            //++ increment the value by 1. initially all values are 0 for Count Array
            //so Count[3] will be 0++ which is equal to 1
            //so Count[3]=1

            //and so on for other indices.

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            //Here 0 format specifier is giving value of Count[i]
            //1 format specifier is giving value of Count[i]
            //2 is doing nothing since there is not corresponding parameter
            Console.Write("{0,2} Adet {1,2} >>>>", Count[i], i + 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < Count[i]; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
```